# AWS Internal HTTPS call to ALB with custom certificate from Lambda code java

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm trying to do an HTTPS call to ALB (It has custom certificate attached via listener) via its DNS name which is managed by AWS and looks something like "internal-name-account.eu-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com". The SSL certificate attached to the ALB listener has private domains (e.x *.example.com).

When a java lambda function (inside same VPC) calls the ALB I get the following error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for <internal-<name>-<account>.eu-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.example.com].
```

I can successfully call the ALB when I disable SSL host verification in code, but I was wondering if there is any other solution.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal to have this error since the certificate is bounded to the domain `*.example.com`.

If you are using that certificate on the ALB, then most probably you have domain mapped to that ALB;

e.g `www.example.com` -- maps to --> `alb-public-dns.eu-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com`.

Using the above, the java code should initiate the https connection with `www.example.com` instead of `alb-public-dns.eu-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: The ALB is internal facing. It does receive traffic from outside via Route 53. Is there any way to call it internally?

Comment: If it is internal, it might be a bit tricky to call it using https. Using a typical EC2 instance, you could update the host file to map the domain to the alb's dns. However for lambda function, I'm not sure how to do it.